# Linux script to rename a log filename to start with the date it was last edited

Tags: linux, date, filenames, rename

I have an application log, lets call it app.log that is set to log up to 100MB and then rename itself to app.log-prev and start logging to new file called app.log.  The problem is that when the new app.log grows to 100MB it will replace the old app.log-prev.

Right now I can get around this by manually editing the app.log-prev filename to 2013-09-25app.log-prev.  The 2013-09-15 will be the changed date (the date that the last edit was made to the file).

I would like to make a script that will search for the file app.log-prev in /var/applogs and if the file is present insert the changed date to the start of the filename and move the renamed file to /var/applogs/archived-logs/

Answer (score 2):

Try using [logrotate](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html), that is the type of thing it is for.

The specific option you want to use is `dateext`. See [Examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/logrotate-examples/)